# Gmap for ee - create list of nearby businesses from google maps

Tags: google-maps-for-ee

Is it possible using objectivehtml's google map for expression engine, to look at a particular address (point) then using a radius search pull from google businesses, potentially allowing for refining the search by hospitals, parks, stores, etc - and create a list?

Answer (score 1):

No that's not possible out of the box. Gmap for EE will search your EE entries, not Google's listings. You'd have to write an extension to the Gmap module or ask ObjectiveHTML to do that implementation for you.